# Script stops working console dont give error (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, project

```js
function createGrid() {
    const deckContainer = document.getElementById('deck-container');

    for (let x = 1; x <= 6; x++) { // For each column
        for (let y = 1; y <= 6; y++) { // For each row
            const index = (y - 1) * 6 + x; // Calculate index based on x and y
            const cardColor = colorDeck[index - 1].color; // Get the color from the shuffled deck

            const card = document.createElement('div');
            card.className = 'card';
            card.dataset.index = index;
            card.id = `card-${index}`;
            card.dataset.color = cardColor;
            card.dataset.revealed = 'false';

            // Create front side of the card
            const cardFront = document.createElement('div');
            cardFront.className = 'card-front';


            // Create back side of the card
            const cardBack = document.createElement('div');
            cardBack.className = 'card-back';

            // Append front and back to the card
            card.appendChild(cardFront);
            card.appendChild(cardBack);

            // Add event listener for click
            card.addEventListener('click', function() {
                handleCardClick(this);
            });

            deckContainer.appendChild(card);
        }
    }
}

function createCenterPointsGrid() {




// Define a variable to store the highlighted card
var highlightedCard;
var revealCardButton = document.getElementById("revealCardButton");
var selectedIndices = [];
let canRollDice = true; // Flag to track if dice can be rolled

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (canRollDice) {
            rollDice();
        } else {
            revealCard();
        }
    });
});

function rollDice() {
    // Reset the selectedIndices array for a new round
    selectedIndices = [];

    if (highlightedCard || !canRollDice) {
        return; // Exit the function if a card is still highlighted or dice can't be rolled
    }

    canRollDice = false; // Disable rolling until revealCard is used

    var dice1 = document.getElementById("dice1");
    var dice2 = document.getElementById("dice2");

    // Apply the "roll" class to initiate the rolling animation
    dice1.classList.add("dice");
    dice2.classList.add("dice");

    // Create an array with the file names of all 6 possible dice faces
    var diceFaces = ["nummer1.PNG", "nummer2.PNG", "nummer3.PNG", "nummer4.PNG", "nummer5.PNG", "nummer6.PNG"];

    // Shuffle the diceFaces array
    shuffleArray(diceFaces);

    // Function to shuffle an array
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
    }

    // Switch dice images during the animation
    for (let i = 0; i < diceFaces.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dice1.src = diceFaces[i];
            dice2.src = diceFaces[i];
        }, i * 250); // Switch every 250 milliseconds, adjust the timing as needed
    }

    // After switching all faces, randomly select the final face
    setTimeout(() => {
        var result1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
        var result2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

        dice1.src = `nummer${result1}.PNG`;
        dice2.src = `nummer${result2}.PNG`;

        // Calculate the index based on the original axis
        var selectedIndex = (result1 - 1) * 6 + (6 - result2) + 1;

        // Check if the selected index has already been selected
        while (selectedIndices.includes(selectedIndex)) {
            // Move to the next index
            selectedIndex = (selectedIndex % 36) + 1; // Assuming 36 cards in total
        }

        var selectedCard = document.getElementById(`card-${selectedIndex}`);

        if (selectedCard) {
            // Highlight the selected card
            selectedCard.classList.add("selected");

            // Set the highlighted card
            highlightedCard = selectedCard;

            // Show the "Reveal Card" button
            revealCardButton.style.display = "block";

            // Add the index to the selected indices list
            selectedIndices.push(selectedIndex);

            // Remove the "dice" class to reset the animation for the next roll
            setTimeout(() => {
                dice1.classList.remove("dice");
                dice2.classList.remove("dice");

                canRollDice = true; // Enable rolling for the next roll
            }, 1500); // Adjust the timing to match the animation duration
        }
    }, diceFaces.length * 250); // Adjust the timing to match the animation duration
}

revealCardButton.addEventListener("click", revealCard);

function revealCard() {
    console.log("Before reveal: ", highlightedCard);

    if (highlightedCard) {
        handleCardClick(highlightedCard);

        console.log("After handleCardClick: ", highlightedCard);

        // Remove the highlight class
        highlightedCard.classList.remove("selected");

        // Reset the highlighted card variable
        highlightedCard = null;

        console.log("After reset: ", highlightedCard);

        // Hide the "Reveal Card" button
        revealCardButton.style.display = "none";

        // Reset canRollDice to true
        canRollDice = true;
    }
}

let RevealedCards = [];

function handleCardClick(card) {
    let cardIndex = parseInt(card.dataset.index, 10); // Get the card's index

    // Toggle the flip effect
    card.classList.toggle('flipped');

    // Only proceed if the card has not been revealed yet
    if (card.dataset.revealed === 'false') {
        card.style.backgroundColor = card.dataset.color; // Reveal the color
        card.dataset.revealed = 'true';
        CardsStatus.push(cardIndex);
        RevealedCards.push(cardIndex);//Push voor updating 

        //console.log(cardIndex);
        //console.log(RevealedCards);
        //console.log(Numofpawns);
        //console.log(availablePositions);


        updateCardPawnPlacements(cardIndex);

        let indicesForCard = findIndicesForValue(allMatrices, cardIndex); // Find the indices
        if (Array.isArray(indicesForCard)) {

            updateCenterPointsColor(indicesForCard); // Kleur de kaarten rood en update hun status

            indicesForCard.forEach(index => { //Blokkeert de indexen van de revealed om nogmaals te worden gewijzigd
                if (!allRevealedCenterPointIndices.includes(index)) {
                    allRevealedCenterPointIndices.push(index);
                }
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
            updatePawnPlacements(indicesForCard);// Herplaatst de pionnen
            }, 100);
            //updateCenterPointsColor(indicesForCard);// 2e x om de mogelijk pawn overwrtites te herstellen, heeft wss geen zin omdat ze al geblokeerd staan in allrevealed


        } else {
            console.error('Expected an array of indices, but received:', indicesForCard);
        }

        // For vertical center points
        let verticalCardIndex = cardIndex; // This could be different if your vertical logic requires
        let verticalIndicesForCard = findIndicesForValue(verticalMatrix, verticalCardIndex);
        if (Array.isArray(verticalIndicesForCard)) {

            updateVerticalCenterPointsColor(verticalIndicesForCard);


            verticalIndicesForCard.forEach(index => { 
                if (!allRevealedVerticalCenterPointIndices.includes(index)) {
                    allRevealedVerticalCenterPointIndices.push(index);
                }
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
            updateVerticalPawnPlacements(verticalIndicesForCard);
            }, 100);
            //updateVerticalCenterPointsColor(verticalIndicesForCard);

        } else {
            console.error('Expected an array of indices, but received:', verticalIndicesForCard);
        }

        // For horizontal center points
        let horizontalCardIndex = cardIndex; // This could be different if your horizontal logic requires
        let horizontalIndicesForCard = findIndicesForValue(horizontalMatrix, horizontalCardIndex);
        if (Array.isArray(horizontalIndicesForCard)) {

            updateHorizontalCenterPointsColor(horizontalIndicesForCard);

            horizontalIndicesForCard.forEach(index => {
                if (!allRevealedHorizontalCenterPointIndices.includes(index)) {
                    allRevealedHorizontalCenterPointIndices.push(index);
                }
            });

            setTimeout(() => {
            updateHorizontalPawnPlacements(horizontalIndicesForCard);
            }, 100);
            //updateHorizontalCenterPointsColor(horizontalIndicesForCard);


        } else {
            console.error('Expected an array of indices, but received:', horizontalIndicesForCard);
        }   }};     

        // Call this function after the center points grid is created
window.onload = function() {
    createGrid();
    createCenterPointsGrid();
    createVerticalCenterPointsGrid();
    createHorizontalCenterPointsGrid();


    // Place pawns after the center points grid is set up
    setTimeout(() => {
        //placePawns(4);// plaats 4 pionnen
        placePawns(4);

    }, 100); // Delay to ensure the grid is fully created before placing pawns
};

document.getElementById('rollDiceButton').addEventListener('click', rollDice);
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



body {
  /*  background-image: url(bruine-houtstructuur-achtergrondafbeelding-met-hoge-resolutie.jpg); */
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    min-height: 100vh; 
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: radial-gradient(circle, #fcfcff 10%, transparent 11%);
    background-size: 3em 3em;
    background-color: #0d9b2e;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #008332;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='48' height='48' viewBox='0 0 48 48'%3E%3Cg fill='%230c581f' fill-opacity='0.5'%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='evenodd' d='M5 3.59L1.46.05.05 1.46 3.59 5 .05 8.54l1.41 1.41L5 6.41l3.54 3.54 1.41-1.41L6.41 5l3.54-3.54L8.54.05 5 3.59zM17 2h24v2H17V2zm0 4h24v2H17V6zM2 17h2v24H2V17zm4 0h2v24H6V17z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  }


  .controls-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    top: 94px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 150px;
    width: 600px;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.dice-container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    display: flex;
  }

  .container-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  button {
    margin-right: 20px; /* Adjust the margin as needed */
    background-color: #fbeee0;
    border: 2px solid #422800;
    border-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: #422800 4px 4px 0 0;
    color: #422800;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 18px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    touch-action: manipulation;
  }

  button:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  #dice1,
  #dice2 {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 0 10px; /* Adjust the space between dice elements as needed */
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f0eaea;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    text-align: center;
  }



.deck-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 80vw; /* 80% of viewport width */
  height: 80vh; /* 80% of viewport height */
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 8px; /* Increase border-radius for a smoother look */
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Increase box-shadow for more depth */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  transform: perspective(1000px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) scale(1); /* Adjust rotation and scale for a flat appearance */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease; /* Add a smooth transition on hover or other interactions */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.selected {
    border: 2px solid #f6ff00; /* Set the border properties as per your design */
    z-index: 1; /* Set a higher z-index to bring the selected card to the front */
    /* Additional styling if needed */
}

.card.selected {
    border: 4px solid #f6ff00; /* Corrected the typo here */
    transform: scale(1.2); /* Set the initial scale for the zoom effect */
    transition: transform 0.3s ease; /* Add a smooth transition effect */
    z-index: 1; /* Set a higher z-index to bring the selected card to the front */
    /* Additional styling if needed */
}

.card.zoomed {
    border: 2px solid #f6ff00; /* Set the border properties as per your design */
    transform: scale(1.2); /* Set the initial scale for the zoom effect */
    transition: transform 0.3s ease; /* Add a smooth transition effect */
    z-index: 1; /* Set a higher z-index to bring the zoomed card to the front */
    /* Additional styling if needed */
}
.center-point,
.vertical-center-point,
.horizontal-center-point {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.center-point {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.vertical-center-point {
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, 0);
}

.horizontal-center-point {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0);
}
.pawn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url(pilsie.png);
  background-size: contain; /* or cover, depending on your needs */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 150px; /* Adjust to suitable dimensions */
  height: 150px; /* Adjust to suitable dimensions */
  position: absolute;
}

  .highlight {
    outline: 6px solid yellow; /* Or any other style to highlight the card */
  }

.red {
    background-color: red;
  }

.green {
    background-color: green;
  }

#revealCardButton{
  position: relative;
  left: 276px;
  display: none;
}

@keyframes roll {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) rotateX(0deg) translateY(0);
    }
    20% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-20px);
    }
    40% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) rotateX(0deg) translateY(0);
    }
    60% {
        transform: rotate(540deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-20px);
    }
    80% {
        transform: rotate(720deg) rotateX(0deg) translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(900deg) rotateX(180deg) translateY(-20px);
    }
}

.dice {
    animation: roll 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

}

.dice {
  animation: roll 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.6.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="deck-container" id="deck-container"></div>
    <div class="container-wrapper" id="none">
        <div class="controls-container">
            <button id="rollDiceButton">Roll Dice</button>
            <button id="revealCardButton" style="display:none;">Reveal Card Color</button>
        </div>
        <div class="dice-container">
            <img id="dice1" class="dice-image" src="nummer1.PNG" alt="Dice 1">
            <img id="dice2" class="dice-image" src="nummer1.PNG" alt="Dice 1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: The console]

[image: The field]

The goal is that the dice will give a coordinate on the grid.
When clicked on the screen it rolls the dice and the outcome will highlight a card.

These cards will be revealed on the next click. if a pawn (beerglass) is on the revealed card it should move to another position possibly following the rules of the script.

Unfortunately, the script is stopping in for me at random moments

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue, not just snippets that lack the necessary context (like the HTML this is interacting with.)

Comment: I think i added what you asked me to do. I am new to stackoverflow so I dont know exactly how to use everything

Comment: @TimDresselaerts: What specifically do you mean by "stops working"?  When running the code snippet in the question, how specifically are you testing it and what specific problem are you observing?  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @David Hi David, I expected the card to reveal colour like all the other cards do. It is not happening for some reason and the scripts stops running it is frozen. I tried debugging with console/log but the console does not push any error.

Comment: @TimDresselaerts: The result of executing the code snippet in the question doesn't appear to show any "cards" or "colors" at all.  Perhaps you need to update the [mcve] in the question to demonstrate the problem?  *"I tried debugging with console/log"* - What specific debugging did you do and what specific observation were you able to make in the debugger?  *"but the console does not push any error"* - Not producing runtime errors is a good start, but it's not an indicate that the code works as expected.

Comment: @David I think i included all the code that is necessary

Comment: @TimDresselaerts: I've converted your code into a runnable code snippet, and upon running that code snippet it immediately produces an error on the browser console.  Previously you'd indicated there were no errors on your browser console.  Please clarify.  If the code snippet in the question doesn't demonstrate the problem you're trying to solve, please take some time to update it so that it demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @David unfortunately i cannot get the code smaller to all fit in stackoverflow, i think its because the script must see some center points and locations we created by using javascript. maybe if possible i can place the full program on a website to take a look at?

Comment: @TimDresselaerts: In that case it sounds like you have some additional debugging and investigation to do in order to produce a [mcve] (note the "minimal" part).  If you're not familiar with the use of your browser's debugging tools, particularly the script debugger, then now is a great time to start [using that debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) to step through the code and observe its runtime behaviors.  This can help you narrow the problem to a more specific operation.